# How to access a field's property using another field's value as a key in Mongo DB aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Imagine I have a document called `symbol_rates` structured as:

```
{
  "mainSymbol": "USD",
  "symbolInfo": {
    "USD": {
      "rate": 4.03
    },
    "GBP" : {
      "rate": 3.21
    }
  }
}
```

When using an aggregation stage like `$addFields`, for example, is it possible to easily access the `rate` value for the key stored in `$mainSymbol` (i.e. "USD" in the above case) via the dot notation? Naively, I would like to write something like:

```
// This does NOT work
db.symbol_rates.aggregate([
    {$addFields: { mainSymbolRate: "$symbolInfo.$mainSymbol.rate" }}
]);
```

I would expect the output to look like:

```
{
  "mainSymbol": "USD",
  "mainSymbolRate": 4.03,
  "symbolInfo": {
    "USD": {
      "rate": 4.03
    },
    "GBP" : {
      "rate": 3.21
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea of how I could achieve this?

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/7El8PFitw09  something like this maybe

Comment: maybe bit shorter https://mongoplayground.net/p/qxX3MWzTdcp

Comment: Although @cmgchess' solution with `$objectToArray` works here, it is suggested to avoid using dynamic values as field names. Consider refactoring your `symbolInfo` object into array like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RxD9eljQ0bM). You can potentially gain a performance advantage through indexing.

Comment: @cmgchess Thank you for the suggestion! This certainly does the trick. I'm still a little surprised that MongoDB doesn't offer something less verbose. At the end of the day, what I need is simply a dynamic key selection feature.

Comment: @ray Appreciate that. Just to add a little context to my question, the above document structure is actually rather contrived. My real world case was actually that a similar structure was an output of one of the aggregation stages. When using MongoDB for reporting/analytics I personally find this particular problem to be very common. As a programmer, I assumed that the most performant solution would be accessing the key dynamically, but sadly such feature is missing.

Comment: yeah it sucks but i guess there is probably a very good reason why dynamic key lookup cant be done.